# I am trying to upload my google drive excel workbook into google collab

Tags: excel, upload

I have an excel workbook saved into my google drive. I need this workbook read in google collab. I attempted to use the following:

shareable_link = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lfamu-yUYAZIzElBmB81D5n747r-F0jb/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100450565935108478338&rtpof=true&sd=true'
gdown.download(shareable_link, 'Beef_data.xlsx', quiet = False)

import pandas as pd

pd.read_excel('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lfamu-yUYAZIzElBmB81D5n747r-F0jb/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100450565935108478338&rtpof=true&sd=true')

please help rectify this.